# Bootstrap page breaking and not responsive under 768px

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and my login page is not responsive under 768px.
The page is breaking as shown in the pictures:

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MY Site</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico?v=2" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
    <meta content='text/html;charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
    <meta content='Saúde Inteligente Móvel' name='description'>
    <link href='~/favicon.ico?v=2' rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon'>
    <link href='~/assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed'>
    <link href='~/assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='57x57'>
    <link href='~/assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='72x72'>
    <link href='~/assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='114x114'>
    <link href='~/assets/images/meta_icons/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png' rel='apple-touch-icon-precomposed' sizes='144x144'>
    <!-- / START - page related stylesheets [optional] -->

    <!-- / END - page related stylesheets [optional] -->
    <!-- / bootstrap [required] -->
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / theme file [required] -->
    <link href="~/Content/light-theme.css" media="all" id="color-settings-body-color" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- / coloring file [optional] (if you are going to use custom contrast color) -->
    <link href="~/Content/theme-colors.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/javascripts/ie/html5shiv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/javascripts/ie/respond.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/site-css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/libs/modernizr")

</head>
<body class='contrast-blue login contrast-background'>
    <div class='middle-container' style="display: none" data-bind="visible: true">
        <div class='middle-row'>
            <div class='middle-wrapper'>
                <div class='login-container-header'>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                <div class='text-center'>
                                    <h1 class="text-primary"><img src="~/Images/logo-sim.png" height="160" width="225" /></h1>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='login-container'>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <div class='row' data-bind="validationOptions: {
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: false,
    parseInputAttributes: true
}">
                            <div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4'>
                                <h1 class="text-center">


                                </h1>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                        <div class="validation-summary" data-bind="visible: model().isAnyMessageShown()">
                                            <ul>
                                                <li data-bind="validationMessage: model().Email"></li>
                                                <li data-bind="validationMessage: model().Senha"></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <form>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <div class='controls with-icon-over-input'>
                                            <input value="" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" data-bind="value: model().Email" name="email" type="email" />
                                            <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='form-group'>
                                        <div class='controls with-icon-over-input'>
                                            <input value="" placeholder="Senha" class="form-control" data-bind="value: model().Senha" name="password" type="password" />
                                            <i class='icon-lock text-muted'></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class='checkbox'>
                                        <label for='remember_me'>
                                            <input id='remember_me' name='remember_me' type='checkbox' data-bind="checked: model().CookiePersistente">
                                            Lembrar de mim
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button class='btn btn-block' data-bind="click: submit">Entrar</button>
                                </form>
                                <div class='text-center'>
                                    <hr class='hr-normal'>
                                    @Html.ActionLink("Esqueceu sua senha?", "EsqueciSenha", "Login")
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='login-container-footer'>
                    <div class='container'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                <div class='text-center'>
                                    <img src="~/Images/logo-rodape.png" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/libs/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/libs/base")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        RouteUtility.rootPath = '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/pages/login.js")"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

After adding col-xs-* as suggested, a weird behaviour is happening. 
When I add col-xs-*, the fields will fit only with 768px and up. If it's under 768px they will grow!! 
It's totally the opposite!
How to fix this?

Under 768px: http://postimg.org/image/d0zcna7bf/

768px and up: http://postimg.org/image/56isu0qtt/

Comment: This is not the problem. Bootstrap is working fine. I'm using ASP. NET MVC. Stylesheets are declared in BundleConfig.

Comment: read up on the grid system here http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  you will probably need to use col-xs-*, replace the * with your desired size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thiago** Hi there.

Have a look around line number **60** in you code for this...
`<div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4'>`

When your screen size hits this breakpoint it will expand to 100% width because you are not controlling/using the **col-xs-XX** class here.
If you add this to your code like this...
`<div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2'>`
for the line of code around line **60** and resize the window, you will see you have control.

This line of code you are using it is used to wrap the Form block, to set the width of this Form.
You just need to take control of this at all breakpoints.

Hope this helps.

**Added to this**
This is what I get when resized.
Using... `<div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2'>` 
[image]

Comment: It didn't work. Page loads with the small fields. When I resize to under 768px, the fields still grow again.

Comment: Hi thiago, Can you please explain what did not work?  Some more detail please. Do you mean this div wrapper grows to 100%? That holds the form.What I provide will work, the form will resize to a 8 column width with a offset of 2 columns. You can adjust this to what suits you, but you need to be mindful how this will look on very small screens. Provide some more detail as to what you are expecting or wanting this to look like below 768px screen size.

Comment: I found out the problem. I have two images placed in the top and bottom of the page. If I remove them, the code you suggested works like a charm. I believe the images need to be responsive as well, right? But adding <div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2'> to theirs divs didn't work. How can I achieve this? The div names are login-container-header  and login-container-footer

Comment: Okay. I made it work using "img-responsive" class. Thanks  AngularJR! you're the man!

Comment: Hi there, moring here. Ok, sounds like you have it working how you want it to now. Just ask if you have any questions about this. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the width for xs device adding eg col-xs-6 :

```
<div class='form-group'>
      <div class='controls with-icon-over-input col-xs-6'>
          <input value="" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" data-bind="value: model().Email" name="email" type="email" />
           <i class='icon-user text-muted'></i>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Fields are side by side now but still breaking